# Logging in with Selenium then submitting requests with Python Requests gives error 401

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I have the following code to log in to a website with Selenium, then submit a request with Requests. I can't easily stick to just requests or just Selenium for this project. I need both. Selenium successfully logs in, but Requests gives an error 401 with any requests I submit. The Requests code was generated by Insomnia, and it works fine if I pass through cookies from my browser after manually logging in. I'm not sure what I need to do to get this to work. Any help is appreciated!

```
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import requests

webdriver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
session = requests.Session()

webdriver.get("example.website")

email_field = WebDriverWait(webdriver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "username-field")))
email_field.send_keys("username")
password_field = WebDriverWait(webdriver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "password-field")))
password_field.send_keys("password")
WebDriverWait(webdriver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "login-button"))).click()

WebDriverWait(webdriver, 10).until(EC.url_matches("loggedin.url"))

for cookie in webdriver.get_cookies():
    session.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])

webdriver.close()

url = "url.for/request"

headers = {
    "authority": "authority.url",
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,de-DE;q=0.8,de;q=0.7,en-GB;q=0.6",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "referer": "referal.url",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "Linux",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0"
}
response = session.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Did you check if there any other HTTP headers set when doing a request in the browser? Some websites use some kind of token in a custom HTTP header in addition to the cookies.

Comment: All those should be it. Insomnia auto grabs all headers and cookies needed for a given request

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem has been to use the [selenium requests](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-requests/) package rather than selenium. This allows you to authenticate using selenium and then use that same webdriver object to send requests to specific APIs.

I never found the root cause for trying to re-use the cookies from selenium with a different session, but I suspect the issue was the original authentication knew the webdriver or session being authenticated, so when you switch your authentication token is no longer valid.